# Partial string matching in javascript

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have this javascript function:

```
var y;
y = ['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('b')
```

This returns -1 because **b** is not a full match against **ab**
In javascript, what is the easiest way of looking for a partial match.

So I want :

```
y = ['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('b')
```

to return 0(index of first element because it found a partial match while comparing **b** to **ab**

I understand i cannot do it using indexOf, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through the Array:

```js
var arr = ['ab', 'f', 'c']

function find(a, c) {
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if(a[i].indexOf(c) != -1)
      return i
  }
  
  return -1
}

// Example:
document.body.innerHTML = find(arr, "b")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple way, you can use the method `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
var testRegex = /b/;
var result = ['ab','f','c'].map(function(item, index) {
      return testRegex.test(item) ? index : null; //return index in the array if found.
}).filter(function(index) {
   return index !== null;  // filter the result and remove all results that are null;
});
```

result should equal `[0]`;

if you try with an array like this:

```
['ab', 'cgt', 'abcd', 'cd', 'efb'];
```

It should return:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 `Array.prototype.findIndex` and arrow functions:

```
y = ['ab', 'f', 'c'];
y.findIndex(el => el.indexOf('b') > -1); //0
```

Comment: wouldn't findIndex return only the first index found? or, to be more precise: what about an array like this: ['b','ab','bc'] ? not that it's asked for in the question, just curious. haven't worked with much of the es6-funcs yet

Comment: It will only  return the first index.